# Compute 5 to the power of 3, but it returns 0. Why?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>

double power (double z, int n)
{
    double result(0.0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        result *= z;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int index(3);
    double x(5.0), double y(0.0);
    y = power (x, index);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, where is the mistake in this code, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the `std::pow` function in the C standard library?

Comment: sorry, i am beginner in C++ and I want to learn how to create function.

Comment: Is this exponential algorithm to find power is the best you can invent/find? There exists pretty obvious linear algorithm.

Comment: This algorithm is linear in `n`. You want a O(1) algorithm

Comment: @Serge: I hardly think it matters at this point!  And anyway, this is already O(n); you're thinking of the O(log n) algorithm.

Comment: @drhirsch, @Oli "this is already O(n); you're thinking of the O(log n) algorithm" True. But `n` is *value* of the input. When someone talk about linear algorithms it means linear function of size of the input. size of the input is log(n).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `result` is initialised to `0`.  And as we know, `0 * anything == 0`.  You need to start at `1`.

*[In future, please learn how to debug!  You would easily have spotted this if you had stepped through your code in a debugger, or added some `printf` statements to your function.]*

Answer (score 1):

Mistake is `double result(0.0);`. 0 multiplied by anything is 0.

Must be `double result(1.0);`

Comment: Actually zero multiplied by NaN isn't zero :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: My statement was mathematical. The is no such thing as NaN in math. :) Well let's stop flooding.

Answer (score 1):

In your power function, your `result` is initialized to be 0.0, then when you multiply it by z n times, you just multiply 0 by z.

You should change `double result(1.0);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your result should be initialized to 1.0 not to 0.0.